# Disable specific keybinding in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I ran into a problem with my keyboard lately, my <kbd>-</kbd> and <kbd>=</kbd> stopped working and I manually remapped the two keys to <kbd>PgUp</kbd> and <kbd>PgDn</kbd> by editing `/usr/share/X11/xkb/keycodes/evdev`. Everything works fine but the problem is that **vscode**  still recognizes these two keys as Page-Up and Page-Down while other editors respect my new config. The question is "How do I make **vscode** adapt to my new configuration"?.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to solve this problem by deleting all the keyboard shortcuts associated with the remapped keys. All I did was opened,

**File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts**, searched for the word **PageUp**, right-clicked the matching words and deleted them all. I did same for **PageDown** and everything works fine now.